# security component of cakephp restricts form submission

Tags: security, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, form-submit

I am facing a strange problem with the security component.

I have a form with following fields in it:

```
First Name (firstname)
Last Name (lastname)
Primary Email (primaryemail)
Password (password)
Retype Password
Secondary Email (secondaryemail)
Residence Address (address)
State
City (city_id)
Location (location_id)
Designation (employeetype_id)
Pincode (pincode)
Residence Phone (residencephone)
Mobile Phone (mobilephone)
Office Phone 1 (officephone1)
Office Phone 2 (officephone2)
Department (department_id)
```

all the fields mentioned above which have a secondary name in brackets are the fileds which are present in database table and those who have not are not there in the database table.

i.e.
I have added states, retype password as an extra in the form.

The main problem is that the "Security" component is blocking from adding a new record to the databse table.

I have added the above two fields to the ignored list array but it still doesn't submits and **generates a blackholed request**.

The code for add method of controller is as follows:

```
function add()
{
    if( !empty($this->data) )
    {
        $this->Employee->create();
        if( $this->Employee->save($this->data) )
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee has been saved', true), 'success');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        else
        {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The employee could not be saved. Please, try again.', true), 'error');
        }
    }

    $states = $this->Employee->City->State->find('list', array(
        'order' => array('name ASC')
    ));

    $employeetypes = $this->Employee->Employeetype->find('list', array(
        'conditions' => array('Employeetype.id <> ' => '1'),
        'order' => array('name ASC')
    ));

    $departments = $this->Employee->Department->find('list', array(
        'order' => array('name ASC')
    ));

    $locations = $this->Employee->Location->find('list', array(
        'order' => array('name ASC')
    ));

    $this->set(compact('states', 'employeetypes', 'departments', 'locations'));
}
```

View file add.ctp is having the following code:

```
<div class="employees form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Employee');?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php __('New Employee'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->element('employee_form');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>
</div>
```

and the code for the element "employee_form" is as follows:

```
<?php
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.validate.min');
echo $this->Html->script('common');
echo $this->Html->script('jquery.typewatch');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("form").validate({
            errorClass: "jqueryError",
            errorElement: 'label',
            debug: false,
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $(':submit', form).attr('disabled', 'disabled').addClass('inactive');
                form.submit();
            }
        });

        $('#EmployeeStateId').change(function() {
            if($('#EmployeeStateId').val() != "")
            {
                populateSelectBox('EmployeeCityId', 'get', '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'cities', 'action' => 'getCities', 'admin' => false)); ?>', {stateId: $(this).val()});
            }
            else
            {
                $('#EmployeeCityId').empty();
            }
        });

        $('#EmployeePrimaryemail').typeWatch(750, function(){
            var $email = $('#EmployeePrimaryemail');
            var $response = $('#response');
            var $btnSubmit = $('submit');
            var re = new RegExp("^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$");

            if($email.val() != '' && re.test($email.val()) )
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'get',
                    url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'checkEmail', 'admin' => false)); ?>',
                    data: {
                        email: $email.val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'text',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        if(data == '1')
                        {
                            $response.attr('style', '')
                            .attr('style', "color:red;")
                            .html('Email already registered please enter a different email.');
                            $btnSubmit.attr('disabled',true);
                        }
                        else if(data == '0')
                        {
                            $response.attr('style', '')
                            .attr('style', "color:green;")
                            .html('Available');
                            $btnSubmit.attr('disabled',false);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $response.attr('style', '')
                            .attr('style', "color:red;")
                            .html('Error occured while attempting to connect with the server. Please try again after some time.');
                            $btnSubmit.attr('disabled',true);
                        }
                    },
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        $email.addClass('show_loading_in_right')
                    },
                    complete: function(){
                        $email.removeClass('show_loading_in_right')
                    }
                });
            }
            else
            {
                $response.attr('style', '')
                .attr('style', "display:none;")
                .html("");
            }
        });

    });
</script>

<?php
echo $this->Form->input('firstname', array(
    'label' => 'First Name',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Only letters and numbers, atleast 2 characters)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('lastname', array(
    'label' => 'Last Name',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Atleast 3 characters)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('primaryemail', array(
    'label' => 'Primary Email',
    'class' => 'required email',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(This will be your username)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Html->div('', '', array(
    'id' => 'response', 'style' => 'display:none'
));

echo $this->Form->input('password', array(
    'label' => 'Password',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Atleast 4 characters long)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('retypePassword', array(
    'label' => 'Retype Password',
    'type' => 'password',
    'equalto' => '#EmployeePassword',
    'class' => 'required',
    'secure' => false,
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Should be exactly same as password entered above)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('secondaryemail', array(
    'label' => 'Secondary Email',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your secondary email, if any)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('state_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'secure' => false,
    'options' => $states,
    'empty' => 'Select',
    'label' => 'State',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Choose your state)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('city_id', array(
    'label' => 'City',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Choose your city)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('address', array(
    'label' => 'Residence Address',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your address)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('pincode', array(
    'label' => 'Pincode',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter pincode)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('residencephone', array(
    'class' => 'required',
    'label' => 'Residence Phone',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your phone number, if any)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('mobilephone', array(
    'label' => 'Mobile Phone',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your mobile number, if any)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('location_id', array(
    'label' => 'Location',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Choose your work location)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('employeetype_id', array(
    'class' => 'required',
    'label' => 'Your Profile',
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $employeetypes,
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Select your company profile or role)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('officephone1', array(
    'class' => 'required',
    'label' => 'Office Phone 1',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your office\'s number 1, if any)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('officephone2', array(
    'label' => 'Office Phone 2',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Enter your office\'s number 2, if any)', array('class' => 'description'))
));

echo $this->Form->input('department_id', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $departments,
    'label' => 'Department',
    'class' => 'required',
    'between' => $this->Html->tag('span', '(Choose your department)', array('class' => 'description'))
));
?>
```

What might be the problem ? I don't want to disable the validatePost property in the controller.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am using the latest version of cakephp (1.3.3)

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the FormHelper to create those fields? FYI, the SecurityComponent doesn't care whether the fields are part of the model or not, only that they were in the original form.

Comment: @deceze: yes I am using FormHelper to create those fields ? Mentioned about the additionally added fields to give a complete scenario of the problem.

Comment: Do you alter anyhow submitted post request? Do you have any fields in the form that are disabled? Do you alter any form fields with javascript? It would be helpful if you post your security component configuration, add() or edit() method and you form view.

Comment: @bancer: okay. I have now edited my question accordingly to include the code for add() method of controller. I haven't done any configuration to the security component except for adding it to the var $components array.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [cookbook](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1296/Security-Component) "Dynamically altering the fields that are submitted in a POST request (e.g. disabling, deleting or creating new fields via JavaScript) is likely to trigger a black-holing of the request." I think your problem caused by javascript. Try to create the form without javascript and see how it works.

Comment: Right, but further it says "See the `$validatePost` or `$disabledFields` configuration parameters." To fix this problem, you need to add these dynamic fields to the `$disabledFields` list, so their absence won't trigger a black-holing.

Comment: that is why I have posted my complete code here so that it may be clear from it that I haven't done anything (altering the value of form fields through javascript) that makes the "Security" component angry :-) I think I will have to leave the usage of 'Security' component for now.